# How to click on mail using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, email, selenium, selenium-webdriver, frameworks

I want to open the mail by clicking on it, after receiving the activation mail.
For that I am using keyword driven framework.

So can anyone please let me know that how can we click on element **without using List<>**.
Because in my coding structure I am returning the object of **Webelement** instead of **List<> object**.

Note: Please suggest the solution without using JavaMail Api or if suggest please let me know according to the keyword driven framework.

**Way of code structure where I find the elements in one method and in another method after getting an element perform the operations:**

```
private boolean operateWebDriver(String operation, String Locator,
            String value, String objectName) throws Exception {
        boolean testCaseStep = false;

        try {
            System.out.println("Operation execution in progress");
            WebElement temp = getElement(Locator, objectName);

            System.out.println("Get Element ::"+temp);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            //For performing click event on any of the button, radio button, drop-down etc.
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
                temp.click();
            }

            /*Trying to click on subject line of "Email"*/
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click_anElement")) {

                Thread.sleep(6000L);

                Select select = new Select(temp);
                List<WebElement> options= select.getOptions();
                for(WebElement option:options){
                    System.out.println(option.getText());
                }

                /*try
                {
                   if(temp.getText().equals(value)){
                             temp.click();
                   }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getCause());
                }*/

                    /*if (value != null) {
                        temp.click();
                }*/
            }


            }

            testCaseStep = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred operateWebDriver"
                    + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Taking Screen Shot");
            TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot)driver;
            File source=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./Screenshots/"+screenshotName+".png"));
            System.out.println("Screenshot taken");
        }

        return testCaseStep;
    }

    public WebElement getElement(String locator, String objectName) throws Exception {
        WebElement temp = null;

        System.out.println("Locator-->" + locator);
        if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));

        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName));
            System.out.println("xpath temp ----->" + temp);
        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.name(objectName));
        }else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("cssSelector")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(objectName));
        }

        return temp;

    }
```

Comment: Please update, what have you tried already?
Also, the structure of your webpage.

Comment: @Haxor Please find the updated post. Also, for the structure of web page you can check gmail, because I want to click on mail and open it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

Comment: More importantly, you haven't told us what the problem or error is, so it's impossible for us to help meaningfully.

Comment: @AndrewRegan I have mentioned above that "How can we click on element without using List<>." means I am not able to click on mail using Webelement object. Also, if possible please let me know the solution without using Java mail api and List< >.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Haxor I am getting "Exception occurred operateWebDriverUnable to locate element {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/h2"} Command duration or timeout: 5.18 seconds"

Comment: @Haxor Actually its not getting the element, I have tried it by giving id or absolute xpath but bot able to click on mail and problem is that I don't want to use java mail api.